# How to get a subset from JSON using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have JSON data such as:

```
[{slug: 'a'}, {slug: 'b'}, {slug: 'c'}, {slug: 'd'}]
```

Now I want to write code in my controller so that when I pass `b` to it, it should return:

```
[{slug: 'b'}, {slug: 'c'}, {slug: 'd'}]
```

Please suggest a good way to achieve this with AngularJS.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need a function like this:

```
var takeStartingAt = function (data, start) {
  var result = [],
      skip = true;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].slug === start) { skip = false; }
    if (skip) { continue; }

    result.push(data[i]);
  }

  return result;
};
```

That's it. Now you can use this function as follows:

```
var data = [
  { slug: 'a' },
  { slug: 'b' },
  { slug: 'c' },
  { slug: 'd' }
];
var filteredData = takeStartingAt(data, 'b');
```

Then `filteredData` will be an array that only contains the objects starting from `slug: 'b'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will work for you

```
function invert(obj, start) {
  var arrObj=[];
  var isStart=false;
  for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){ 
  var ob=obj[i];
  for (var prop in ob) {
    if(ob.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {

        if(ob[prop]==start){
             isStart=true;
        }   
        if(isStart){
         arrObj.push(ob);
        }

    }
  }    
 }

  return arrObj;
};

var ob1= invert ([{slug: 'a'}, {slug: 'b'}, {slug: 'c'}, {slug: 'd'}],'c');
alert(JSON.stringify(ob1));
```

**[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nBQ2D/2/)**

Comment: could you please elaborate on how to pass the json and the parameter for starting subset?

Comment: I have updated the answer , please check it,now it will work according to your requirement

Comment: Because the code does not answer the question ("so that when I pass `b` to it", you don't even consider this), and - additionally - it does not work. Your demo returns all objects, including the one with slug `a`. Moreover, the code is bad style (`ob`, `prop`, `new_obj`, `arrObj` are inconsistent names, indentation is wrong, … and last but not least, why is the function called `invert`? It does not *invert* anything).

Comment: see , I just put the helping code, user can achieve the goal by some manipulation in code. by the way I have updated the code. and there is nothing to do with bad style inconsistent names.

Comment: Your code is still wrong: You invert key and value, this was not asked for.

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess the question has been update, yeah its wrong according to updated question

Comment: I think, this time I am not wrong, I have updated the code once again, sorry for inconsistent names.